# When did people stop getting Tazra'as?

Tags: history, tzaraas-negaim

At what point in history did Tzra'as stop happening? Was it sudden or gradual? Do we have any sources that suggest that it could still occur today?

Comment: I suppose it's possible that Kohanim stopped declaring it before people stopped getting it (if that ever happened).

Comment: do you have a source that Tzara'as stopped happening?

Comment: http://www.torahmusings.com/2014/04/contemporary-tzaraat/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If nowadays a Cohen declares somebody (or a garment or a house) as having Tzara'at, then that declaration is valid and the laws of Tzara'at kick in. All this assuming that the "blotch" in question has the correct size and color.

The Ramabm in הלכות טומאת צרעת פרק י"א:י"א - says that the process for "curing" the Mezora from Tzara'as is followed even nowadays - even outside of Israel.

Note that the last step in the "curing" process - that of bringing a Korban - is not done, since we don't have a Bet HaMikdash - and is not needed unless the person wants to eat Korbanot (which can't be done nowadays anyway.)

Comment: "is not needed unless the person wants to eat Korbanot"? It's a _mitzva_, innit?

Comment: [I'm not seeing](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx) 11:11 in "_Tum'as Tzaraas_".

Comment: See it here: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a311.htm

יא  [ו] טהרת מצורע זו--נוהגת בארץ ובחוצה לארץ, בפני הבית ושלא בפני הבית

Comment: You asked:
"is not needed unless the person wants to eat Korbanot"? It's a mitzva, innit?"

 Not sure what you are referring to. 1. It is a Mitzva to eat Korbanot, but we can't do that nowadays. 2. It's a Mitzva to Metaher the Metzora, as the Rambam (ibid) says: וכוהן שטימאו, מצווה לטהרו--שנאמר "לטהרו, או לטמאו"

Comment: I meant #2. Bringing a _korban m'tzora_ is (part of) a _mitzva_.

Comment: The Tifferes Yisrael writes in his intro. to Negaim that he asked Rabbi Akiva Eiger why we don't practice the laws of tzaraas. He responded that he was bothered by the same thing and figured that it must be because we lack kohanim meyuchasim. I asked a rabbi who lived more recently why we dont ntice sinners getting tzaraas, and he responded that tzaraas can be very small...

Comment: @mevaqesh - never smaller than a "Gris", about the size of a Shekel coin, IIRC. Besides it can be on (under) a clothed part of the body. Certain types of baldness may qualify too.