# How common was tzaraas?

Tags: history, tzaraas-negaim

*Tzaraas* (discussed in [Vayikra 13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9914)-[14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9915)) is a human skin disease that renders its victim impure and subjects him to many laws. In a different form, 
*tzaraas* can also affect clothing and houses. It is generally understood to be punishment for certain sins, such as talebearing.

As far as I'm aware, *tzaraas* doesn't occur nowadays. But during the era that it did happen, how common was it? Was it a once-in-a-century type thing? Or was it more like if you had a nasty neighbor, you could be pretty sure he'd soon get *tzaraas*? Were some of the three types more common than others?

Comment: Related (and partially conflicting): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17813/3

Comment: re houses: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/46104/759