# Why is there no tzara'at nowadays

Tags: reward-punishment, lashon-hara-slander, tzaraas-negaim

In the Torah it says clearly that the punishment for speaking Lashon Hara' is צרעת. 
Why then do we not see this happening as an immediate or even delayed punishment nowadays? 
And why does the Torah say it will happen if not to this day?

Comment: Where in the Torah does it say that clearly?

Comment: Note it's not clear that there isn't Tzara'at nowadays http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17813/759

Comment: Because actual teshuva is more difficult without korbanot thus everyone is less holy and less worthy of an open miracle to avenge their honor.

Comment: @sabbahillel I don't think that "why" is a duplicate of "when."

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/kahn/archives/metzora68.htm) where the article says

> Nowadays, we do not experience open miracles, and therefore do not see
>   the afflictions of tzaraas.